# Kendo UI grid not refresh automatically in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, kendo-grid

I created a project using Kendo UI Grid, it works very well in Chrome and mozilla. Grids can refresh automatically. but in explorer, it can't! only first time (when page is open first time)  datasource work (script), then datasource not work in refresh time.

This two scenario, grid can not refresh:

1. When I return from "EDİTPAGE", I can see updated values in grid. But in chrome and mozilla, I can see.
2. I have automatic refresh command named `setInterval`, Grid can not refresh again in Explorer. it can only refresh in Chrome and Mozilla.

   ```
       setInterval(function () {
           $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
       }, 10000);    /// not work!


    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                       sortable: true,
                       pageable: {
                           input: true,
                           numeric: false,
                           buttonCount: 5,
                           pageSizes: true
                       },
                       autoBind: true,
                       height: 500,
                       selectable: "row",
                       dataSource: {
                           pageSize: 5,
                           transport: {
                               read: "/Home/Getdata",   //// here works one time in explorer. Then it's not work. I change page and come back again but not work.
                               type: "json"
                           }, schema: {
                               data: "data",
                               total: "total"
                           },
                           serverPaging:true
                       },
                       change: function (e) {
                           var item = this.dataItem(this.select());
                           win.content(template(item));
                           win.open();
                       },  rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#altTemplate").html())
                   }).data("kendoGrid");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Some questions first. What version of IE are you using? Which version of KendoUI for Web are you using? Have you checked your network tab in dev tools to see if there's a 500 err when you load the grid?

Are you binding setInterval() to an event? I suspect that you need to attach it to your document ready function. See [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-data-refresh) example.

Comment: I use IE 11. I use kendoui web 2013 open-source.. In examples, auto refresh is work. But in my project not.

Comment: I would start by using the example in the link I posted. Move your setInterval function inside $(document).ready().

Comment: I look IE network.. when I click "Allways refresh servers" my grid can refresh. But when I reclick it, it doesn't work. it gives result is 304 ....

Comment: I saw in "network" area. my code "getdata" is work... it send request.. result is 304 and 414 B taken... but grid not change.

Comment: A 304 is not the issue. The 414 error indicates that the request uri is too long.